# How to disable certain AWS Cognito APIs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

From my understanding, every method in the actions tab on the left [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html) is a method to be used on the frontend interface of the app meaning that every end user can invoke it. Is there a way to disable certain methods ? For example I do not want the users to be able to use `ResendConfirmationCode` .

Comment: How do you plan on using Cognito? You will need some kind of UI, correct? Mobile app, website, etc? Cognito functionality is a service you can connect to and utilize however you want. If your app/website doesn't have button for `Resend Code` then `ResendConfirmationCode` will never be executed

Comment: @ᴛʜᴇᴘᴀᴛᴇʟ My frontend (react) has all these parameters for ```AWS Amplify``` configuration: ```identityPoolId```, ```region```, ```userPoolId``` and ```userPoolWebClientId```. So even if I do not provide a ```Resend Code``` button as you say, still a user can invoke the action ```ResendConfirmationCode``` if he knows the relevant AWS endpoint by using the aforementioned parameters.

Comment: Short answer - you cannot. Also, not every action can be execute by anyone. Without proper permissions you can't execute admin actions as well as actions for authenticated users. The remaining actions should be rather harmless. Do you have any specific concerns.